# Memory Leak in c linked list insert function

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

I'm trying to implement a linked list and according to LeakSanitizer I have a leak in my program in this function. The function inserts new nodes and keeps them sorted in ascending order.

[image]

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} node;

void insert(node **head, int num) {
    node *temp_node = NULL, *curr = NULL;

    temp_node = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    temp_node->data = num;
    temp_node->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = temp_node;
    } else
    if ((*head)->data >= temp_node->data) {
        temp_node->next = *head;
        *head = temp_node;
    } else {
        curr = *head;
        while (curr->next != NULL && curr->next->data < temp_node->data)
            curr = curr->next;

        temp_node->next = curr->next;
        curr->next = temp_node;
    }
}
```

This is the call to insert in my main function

```
node *head;

...other code...

insert(&head, number);

...other code....

free(head);
```

Any advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Tip: Consider what happens if `curr->next` is NULL....

Comment: You do not initialize `head` in its declaration.  If you do not otherwise assign a value to it before passing its address to `insert()` then that function's use of it will have undefined behavior.

Comment: head was initialize to NULL sorry for not including it. @JohnBollinger

Comment: The code is still incomplete. You only show code that calls `insert` only once. Where is the other code where you call `insert` and the other code where you `free` any additional nodes?

Comment: Its just a while loop that reads number from the user and this is the only place where insert is called @Cheatah

Comment: The `insert()` function presented does not have any inherent memory leak, as determined by inspection and confirmed by building a program around it and testing that via valgrind. No [mre] having been presented, we can only speculate about LeakSanitizer's complaint.  Possibly the issue is just that the program exits without ever attempting to free any of the nodes other than the head.  Possibly something else the program does is causing some of them to leak.

Comment: @Nice And you don't see anything wrong with only freeing the list head without ever freeing the other nodes?

Comment: @Cheatah That solved the problem for some reason, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The leak was being caused because I didn't delete all the nodes once the program finished.
So I used this instead of the `free(head)` at the end of main.

```
void freeList(node* head)
{
    node* temp;

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }

}
```